# Equating JS variable to json encoded php array value regardless of index

Tags: javascript, php

I'm comparing a JS variable to a json encoded php array value, which is working currently as is:

```
function myFunction() {
    var itemArray = <?php echo json_encode($items);?>;   
    console.log(itemArray);

    var number = 14;

    if(number == itemArray[0]['number']){
        success.style.display = "block";
        error.style.display = "none";
    }
}

[{
    0:
        name: "nameOne"
        number: 14
    1:
        name: "nameTwo"
        number: 13
    2:
        name: "nameThree"
        number: 8
}]

$items: array:3 [
    0=>array{
        name: "nameOne"
        number: 14
    }
    1=>array{
        name: "nameTwo"
        number: 13

    }
    2=>array{
        name: "nameThree"
        number: 8
    }
]
```

So It's indexed to zero which is fine for testing the comparison, but this isn't what I want. I want to be able to look at the 'number' field of every index in this object. So basically I want to say "If 14 exists as 'Number' in any of the indeces here, then this should be true".

I want to do this for other fields eventually too, but when I change my index to `if(number == itemArray[]['number']){` then it says the function is undefined.

How can I do this for any index in the object to look at that field?

Comment: You need to have a loop inside your function.

Comment: Thats not valid JSON! So what are you actually using

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's what my console log gives. I think it copied the syntax incorrectly though

Comment: Add $items data in question.

Comment: @ShivendraSingh it has been added

Comment: Your code for $items is not valid PHP and would be generating a syntax error.

Comment: @PatrickQ I've edited it, that is exactly what is being dumped currently and I have no syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//I suppose Your items will be like
$items = 
array(array("name" => "nameOne","number" => 14),
    array("name"=> "nameTwo","number"=> 13),
     array("name"=> "nameThree","number"=> 8)
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($items);
?>

<script>
myFunction();
function myFunction() {
  //Use the JavaScript function JSON.parse() to convert text into a JavaScript object:
   var json  = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($items);?>');   
   console.log(json );

   var number = 14;
   var result = false;
   var error = '';
   //Use the loop to get the value from json
  for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];

   //If obj.number is 14 add your code
   if(number == obj.number){
      result = true;

   }
  }

 if(result){
    alert('success message');
    success.style.display = "block";
    error.style.display = "none";
 }else{
    success.style.display = "none";
    error.style.display = "block";
 }

}
</script>
```

Comment: This works except if one entry in the array doesn't contain it then it won't ever trigger my success. Can I make this so that if the name/number exists in at least one or any spot, then we have success?

Comment: Basically, I have an if/else around that equation so as long as it exists at least once then I want to give a success message, but if it doesn't exist anywhere I'd give an error

Comment: yes. if doesn't exist number you can add message in else.

Comment: I did, but the problem is the number exists in two objects but not the last one, so even though they exist i only get the error message for the one that doesn't exist

Comment: Now check, you will get all the name which not contain the number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196150/discussion-between-shivendra-singh-and-tom-n).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to array an array of objects that match the key try this. The 2nd function returns an array of the matching indices, although there is probably a better way to do that.

```js
var array = [{
        name: "nameOne",
        number: 14
    },{
        name: "nameTwo",
        number: 13

    },{
        name: "nameThree",
        number: 8
    },{
        name: "nameThree",
        number: 14
    }
];
   
function findMatches(array, key, value) {
    return array.filter(item => item[key] == value);
}

function findIndex(array, key, value) {
    return array.map((item,index) => item[key] === value ? index :    undefined).filter(x => x !== undefined);
}
console.log(findMatches(array, "number", 14));
console.log(findIndex(array, "number", 14));
console.log(findMatches(array, "number", 13));
console.log(findIndex(array, "number", 13));
console.log(findMatches(array, "number", 2));
console.log(findIndex(array, "number", 2));
```

Comment: I'm trying to test this now, but just to clarify: Say I have the array with 5 items and only one item has the number I want. As long as at least one exists then I want to give a success message. Will this work for that? Basically I don't care if any don't have it, I just care that at least one has it, or none at all

Comment: Just test it in Fiddle or something.  If that are not matches it should just return an empty array.  If you want the actual index, the second one should work.  If you want the actual object the first one should work.  If you just want to know if there is a match or not you could check the length of the array.